# Does DATE format affect the way dates are compared?

Tags: java, date, format

Say I've got two dates formatted this way:

```
date1 = Feb 22, 2011
date2 = Mon Feb 21 08:30:03 EST 2011 (default formatting)
```

will `date2.compareTo(date1);` still work?
I've got a method I'm using to see if certain date values are the same, but its not working. One date is formatted a certain way, and I think this might be problem.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly are you comparing? Two `Date` instances or two `String` instances? The `Date` doesn't store any information about formatting. All it stores is the epoch time in milliseconds. The `String` in turn knows nothing about the specific information it contains, such as a date representation, the comparison just depends on the natural language rules.

Comment: They're actually two different dates. I was just printing them like that to ask the formatting question. So confused :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will still work. 
The comparison is based on the milliseconds of the date. The formatting is used for display, not comparison.

In your example, check to be sure that date1 is not at 12:00:00 AM, which would be a different time than date2.

Comment: Above was just exmaples, I'm not using this data specifically. However, if I can't get the method to work after a little more hacking I'll start a new question with my method. Thanks!